# Material UI Tabs: After switch between tabs, changes in tabs discarded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I use material ui tab component.
after switch between tabs, changes in tabs discarded.In fact, after switching between tabs, the tabs are rendered again.
Suppose I have a textField in one of the tabs. I enter some inside this textField . After going to another tab and returning, the value inside the textField is cleared.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, After switching tabs in Material UI, invisible tabs will be destroyed and removed from DOM. So, You have to write some logics by yourself(And maybe not using `TabPanel` component).

**First** -> You need to save the current tab's value in your state

**Second** -> Create a `hidden` class

```
 .hidden { display: none; }
```

**Third** -> You need to check if the active tab is the same as index of your tab, you need to assign `hidden` class to it.

P.S: If you look carefully, the main idea of this method is preventing inactive tabs from **displaying** not **rendering**