# React setState not when switching between tabs in Material UI. Applied div with display none but not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I navigate from one Material UI Tab to another, the state does not persist and is cleared.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-meadow-6pw3dk?file=/demo.tsx

I've tried:

- Using React Context to pass in the React State resulting in the same issue

This is a known issue and there exist a workaround found at:

- [Material UI Tabs: After switch between tabs, changes in tabs discarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021679/material-ui-tabs-after-switch-between-tabs-changes-in-tabs-discarded)
- [React MUI Tab component cause re-render and remove child states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72787400/react-mui-tab-component-cause-re-render-and-remove-child-states)

My issue is I've added the tabs div but the page is still not keeping the inactive tabs from unmounting.

```js
export default function LabTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            <Tab label="Item One" value="1" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" value="2" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" value="3" />
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value="1">
          <div style={{ display: "0" === value ? "block" : "none" }}>
            <div>
              [Step 1] Click on "ADD" and note the counter then navigate to TAB
              1.
            </div>
            <Panel />
          </div>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="2">
          <div style={{ display: "1" === value ? "block" : "none" }}>
            [Step 2] Return to Tab 0 and see that the Counter reverted to zero.
          </div>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="3">Item Three</TabPanel>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) or [Redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) might help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use MUI Tabs, only the active tab exists in the DOM. The others aren't hidden; they're destroyed, along with the unsaved state within.

In your example, you're storing the `counter` value with `React.useState` inside your `<Panel />` component, which is inside tab #1. When you click another tab, the Panel is unmounted and fully removed from the DOM, along with the state value within.

To resolve the issue and keep your state, you'll need to lift it up above the tabs so the state doesn't live in an unmounted component. Try adding this to your `demo.tsx` file on line 11:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

Then add those as props to your Panel component on line 33:

```
<Panel counter={counter} setCounter={setCounter} />
```

Finally, in your `panel.tsx` file, use the props instead of the local `useState` values.

```
interface Props {
   counter: number;
   useCounter: (num: number) => void;
};
export default const Panel = ({ counter, useCounter }: Props) => (
  <>
    <div>Counter: {counter}</div>
     <Button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)} variant="contained">
       ADD
    </Button>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Wow that worked!!  :)  Thank you!  It should be noted this worked for my context as well where I placed my custom React Context in the `demo.tsx` on line 11: `const {someContext, setSomeContext} = useCustomContext()  `